# Synchronous IPC between modules of a horizontally scalable web app

Tags: java, web-applications, ipc, scalability, horizontal-scaling

I'm designing a modular web app, that is mainly a web api, with horizontal scalability in mind. My problem is that for some tasks I need two or more modules to exchange data synchronously, but I don't want this to affect the horizontal scalability of my web app. If I could do that asynchronously I would use queues for sure, but with synchronous communication I don't know exactly what to use. Are there some de facto standards or at least some best practices for synchronous communication between web app modules that don't break horizontal scalability?

FWIW, I also coded a demo of this app in PHP, but I plan to migrate to Java soon. However, the solution should be language agnostic.

Thanks

Comment: well I was thinking of JMS, but that is not language agnostic

Comment: Can JMS be synchronous? Moreover, I'd like to use something widely supported because I want to be able to deploy my web app on as many paas providers as possible.

Comment: for more interoperable / language agnostic messaging system I'd look towards https://www.rabbitmq.com with things like http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v2.1.1/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-2.1.1/com/rabbitmq/utility/BlockingCell.html